# mysqlimport without mysql installation?

Tags: mysql, database, linux, mysqlimport

I'm trying to use mysqlimport to import text files to a mysql database.  The problem is that the linux box I am importing the text files from will not have an installation of mysql and I am importing these files to a database on a different server. Does mysqlimport need to have a full installation of mysql to work?  Can I just bring over the mysqlimport exe and some libraries?
Cheers,
Kaiser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it standalone, among the options described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) you can specify host to connect to, and the user and password to use. No need for the box where mysqlimport is to have the server installed.

I believe you need nothing more that the [RPM Package Client Utilities](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads).

Comment: Do you know what i need to have in order to do this? First, I brought over just the exe but it said i needed the library files. So, I brought over all the lib files but now when i run it i get a floating exception and cant even run "mysqlimport --help"

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can connect to the database server from the client you are running on, it is fully enough to have a MySQL client installation.

```
mysqlimport -h host -p port [options] db_name textfile1 textfile2
```

Compare the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html) or execute

```
mysqlimport --help
```

Comment: Should be `-P port`