# Mysqlimport does not work on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysqlimport

i have installed Server version: **5.6.25** MySQL Community Server (GPL) on my laptop with OS ubuntu 14.04 lts. Recently i tried to run [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_help) client program and got errors that i was unable to figure out.

on terminal i type this command and got this error:

```
mysql> mysqlimport --local test_database employee.txt;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport --local test_database employee.txt' at line 1

Initially, i thought that may be the problem is in the  employee.txt file directory which i stored under **var/lib/mysql** directory.But when i tried this most basic mysqlimport command i again got error!:

```
mysql> mysqlimport --help;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqlimport --help' at line 1

Thus, i think my current mysql **5.6.25** does not have mysqlimport support.I tried to follow this [RPM Package Client Utilities.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958346/mysqlimport-without-mysql-installation).However that was for linux not ubuntu & all the given Package versions are **5.6.26** not **5.6.25**.BTW all of my other configurations such as phpmyadmin & database query works fine.

Therefore, in that situation how should i resolve the problem ?
let me know for further information.
Thanks

Thanks alvits , finally i tried this modified commands from outside the mysql in another terminal:
 `mysqlimport --local -u root -p test_database home/himadree/mysqlTestingFiles/employee.txt;`
it works,BUT the data inside the employee.txt were not correctly restored into the table. my actucal  employee.txt contains this tab-dalimated data below:

```
100     John Doe        DBA
200     John Smith      Sysadmin
300     Raj Patel       Developer
```

But after mysqlimport command i got this output:

```
select * from employee;
+-------+-----------------+------+
| empno | ename           | job  |
+-------+-----------------+------+
|   100 | John Doe        | NULL |
|   200 | NULL            | NULL |
|   300 | NULL            | NULL |
+-------+-----------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

why i m getting some incorrect data on the table?

Yes Finally i realized that there were some extra tabs in the text file & last commands were fine.
Now here is my final table:

```
mysql>  select * from employee;
+-------+------------+-----------+
| empno | ename      | job       |
+-------+------------+-----------+
|   100 | John Doe   | DBA       |
|   200 | John Smith | Sysadmin  |
|   300 | Raj Patel  | Developer |
+-------+------------+-----------+
```

So, anyone trying to learn the **mysqlimport** program then be careful:

1. whether  the input text file **properly delimited** or not.
2. use **mysqlimport** program outside from mysql program itself with opening **another terminal/shell** on your OS etc.
   Thanks a lot.

Comment: `mysqlimport` shouldn't be run inside `mysql`. It is an external command. Run it from the shell prompt.

Comment: i opened the mysql using mysql -u root -p in terminal.how to ran mysql from shell prompt in ubuntu? thanks for reply

Comment: You ran `mysql` correctly. However, `mysqlimport` is a separate tool which shouldn't be run inside `mysql`. While you are in shell prompt, instead of running `mysql`, try `mysqlimport --help`. That's how you run `mysqlimport`.

Comment: alvits, i just re-edit my post please reply.thanks

Comment: If you have multiple TABs, extra TABs will count as NULL column. Extra columns are always ignored. You should try `--fields-enclosed-by` and enclose your columns in the txt file. Or use CSV and set `--fields-terminated-by` to comma `,`.

Comment: alvits, you were right & i corrected it now.thank you for useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, shell, I ditched mysqlimport and instead use:
MYSQL -h blah < file.sql